# How to fix incorrect guess in image recognition

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to this stuff so please bear with me. I followed a quick simple video about image recognition/classification in YT and the program indeed could classify the image with a high percentage. But then I do have some other images that was incorrectly classified.

On tensorflow site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#distortions

> However, one should generally avoid point-fixing individual errors in
>   the test set, since they are likely to merely reflect more general
>   problems in the (much larger) training set.

so here are my questions:

1. What would be the best way to correct the program's guess? eg. image is B but the app returned with the results "A - 70%, B - 30%"
2. If the answer to one would be to retrain again, how do I go about retraining the program again without deleting the previous bottlenecks files created? ie. I want the program to keep learning while retaining previous data I already trained it to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is often no easy fix, because the model you are training is highly complex and very hard for a human to interpret.

However, there are techniques you can use to try and reduce your test error. First make sure your model isn't overfitting or underfitting by observing the difference between train and test errors. If either is the case then try applying standard techniques, such as choosing a deeper model and/or using more filters if underfitting or adding regularization if overfitting.

Since you say you are already classifying correctly a high percentage of the time, I would start inspecting misclassified examples directly to try and gain insight into what you might be able to improve.

If possible, try and observe what your misclassified images have in common. If you are lucky they will all fall into one or a small number of categories. Here are some examples of what you might see and possible solutions:

- Problem: Dogs facing left are misclassified as cats
- Solution: Try augmenting your training set with rotations
- Problem: Darker images are being misclassified
- Solution: Make sure you are normalizing your images properly

It is also possible that you have reached the limits of your current approach. If you still need to do better consider trying a different approach like using a pretrained network for image recognition, such as [VGG](https://github.com/machrisaa/tensorflow-vgg).